# FasterXML Hibernate OneToMany get id in xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jackson, fasterxml

I have currently a big problem with Hibernate and Jackson FasterXML.
I have a parent class "Structure Parent" with :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "structureParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Site> sites = new ArrayList<Site>();
```

And a site class with

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "annualStructureId")
@JsonIgnore
private StructureParent structureParent;
```

The problem is I can't display the structureParent in the XML because of an infinite loop but I need the structureParent id in my XML.
Do you know if I could do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Read about this feature: Handle bi-directional references using declarative method(s) - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

Answer (score 0):

You can select only the foreign key(parent's ID) and show on xml this way(jackson 2.1+)

```
@JsonProperty(value = "annualStructureId")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) 
private StructureParent structureParent;
```